# 取得した文字列の操作及び出力python

Tags: python, python3, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

食べログのサイトから営業時間を取得し、平日/土日祝をそれぞれ開始日時と終了日時に分けてcsvに出力できればと考えています。
今の問題は

1. 取得済みの平日/土日祝で別々のリストに入った文字列からxx:xxという時刻の文字列を取り出し出力すること。今のままだと1800みたくなってしまいます。findallで取得したものの中に":"や"～"という文字は除外されてしまうみたいです。
2. ”～”の文字列に反応して開始時刻と終了時刻を別々に区切って出力すること。 18:00~23:00
   なら　18:00と23:00を別々のセルに
3. 全角の文字列にも対処できるようにしたい

以上です宜しくお願いします。

```
import csv
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_dotwlefts(tablink):
    response = requests.get(tablink)
    html = response.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    dotwfound = soup.select_one(
        "#contents-rstdata > div.rstinfo-table > table:nth-child(2) > tbody > tr:nth-child(7) > td > p"
    )
    if dotwfound is not None:
        dotw = dotwfound.text
    if dotwfound is None:
        dotw = ""
    m = re.search(r"\[土|【土|\[土・日【日|土・日|日祝|土日祝|日・祝|\[日・祝|土・日・祝|土日|土、日|\[日", dotw, flags=re.DOTALL)
    y = m.start() if m else None
    dotwlefts = left(dotw, y)
    dotwrights = right(dotw, y)
    if dotwlefts == dotwrights:
        dotwrights = ""
    return dotwlefts


def get_dotwrights(tablink):
    response = requests.get(tablink)
    html = response.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    dotwfound = soup.select_one(
        "#contents-rstdata > div.rstinfo-table > table:nth-child(2) > tbody > tr:nth-child(7) > td > p"
    )
    if dotwfound is not None:
        dotw = dotwfound.text
    if dotwfound is None:
        dotw = ""
    m = re.search(r"\[土|【土|\[土・日【日|土・日|日祝|土日祝|日・祝|\[日・祝|土・日・祝|土日|土、日|\[金|【金|\[日|金/土", dotw, flags=re.DOTALL)
    y = m.start() if m else None
    dotwlefts = left(dotw, y)
    dotwrights = right(dotw, y)
    if dotwlefts == dotwrights:
        dotwrights = ""
    return dotwrights


def left(text, n):
    return text[:n]


def right(text, n):
    return text[n:]


def get_eachpage(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    html = response.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    tablinks = [
        "https://icotto.jp" + each.get("href")
        for each in soup.find_all("a", {"class": "p-presses-show-spot__source--image"})
    ]
    for tablink in tablinks:
        dotwleft = get_dotwlefts(tablink)
        dotwright = get_dotwrights(tablink)
        dotwleft = re.findall(r"[0-9０－９~〜:：]+", dotwleft)
        #dotwleft = "".join(re.findall("[0-9]{1}|[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}～[0-9]{1}|[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}", dotwleft))
        #dotwright = "".join(re.findall("[0-9]{1}|[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}~[0-9]{1}|[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}", dotwright))
        print(dotwleft)
        print(dotwright)


url = "https://icotto.jp/presses/15108"
get_eachpage(url)
```

Comment: 現状のコードだと動かないようです（ `left` という関数が定義されていません。）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

現在掲載されているサンプルコードだと動作しなかったため、標準的な対応方法をそれぞれについて解説します。

### 別々のリストに入った文字列からxx:xxという時刻の文字列を取り出し出力すること。今のままだと1800みたくなってしまいます。findallで取得したものの中に":"や"～"という文字は除外されてしまうみたいです。

現在コメントアウトしている正規表現が原因に見えます。例えば、 `re.findall(r"[0-9~〜:：]+", "spam18:00eggs")` とすることで、 `:` や `〜`を含む文字列を時刻の形式で取得することができます。

### ”～”の文字列に反応して開始時刻と終了時刻を別々に区切って出力すること。 18:00~23:00なら　18:00と23:00を別々のセルに

上記の方法で取り出したあと、  `"10:00〜18:00".split("〜") => ["10:00", "18:00"]` のように、[str.split](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) を使ってみてはいかがでしょうか。

### 全角の文字列にも対処できるようにしたい

これも同様に、文字列の正規表現を `[0-9]` から `[0-9０-９]` に拡張することで対応可能です。また、全角数字を整数に変換することは組み込み関数の `int` で可能です。

```
int("３０") => 30
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。コードを修正しました。上記の解説とても助かり、時刻形式で取得することができたのですが、２つ質問があります。出力が['18:00', '1:00', '24:00']のようになってしまってどれが開始/終了時刻か区別が付かないので、"10:00〜18:00"のような出力にするにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？また、0-9０－９で全角に検索範囲を拡張した後にintでの半角への変換はどの位置に組み込めばいいでしょうか。宜しくお願いします。　　　　　　dotwleft = re.findall(r"[0-9０－９~〜:：]+", dotwleft)

Comment: `['18:00', '1:00', '24:00']` となる例がちょっと分からないのですが（実際のページの例があると良いかもしれません）、間に休憩時間が記載されている場合でしょうか？食べログ側でバリデーションされていない場合、ある程度そのようなエラーは発生すると思うので人力でやるしかなさうです。

Comment: 半角への変換は `int` を使う例を書きましたが、正規表現を使うのがよろしいかもしれません。また、 `mojimoji` というライブラリも全角半角変換に便利なようです。[mojimoji · PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/mojimoji/)

Comment: 実際の上のコード（修正済みです）を動かすと、re.findall(r"[0-9~〜:：]+"をそのまま使うと出力が'18:00', '1:00', '24:00になってしまうので、"10:00〜18:00"のような開始時刻終了時刻をセットにして取り出したいと思っています

Comment: コードの方拝見しましたが、アクセスしている https://icotto.jp/presses/15108 及び各食べログの表記を確認する限りプログラム的に対応するのは非常に難しく（フォーマットが固定ではないため無限にパターンを想像しなければならない）、かつ誤った情報をパースしてしまう可能性が高いため困難そうです。このため、営業時間を記載通りにそのまま出力するか、手入力するのが最も確実かつ早そうです。